# HTML list style image different image on same ul level

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have Application that is creating output with `li` tags. I am trying to figure out how to put `list-style-image` for different `li` tag of the same `ul` level while keeping html as simple as possible. Every `li` class(green, yellow, error) should have its own image instead of the bullet.
As i figured it out, in css "list-style-image" should be style of the `ul`, but it is not working in `li` 
My HTML

```
   <body>
  <div>     
     <ul>
        <li class="green">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li class="yellow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li class="error">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <ul>
           <li class="error">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
              <ul>
                 <li class="error"><a href="test.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></li>
              </ul> 
        </ul>
        <li class="yellow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li class="green">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li class="green">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li class="error">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <ul>
           <li class="error">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
              <ul>
                 <li class="error"><a href="test.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></li>
                 <li class="error"><a href="test.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></li>
                 <li class="error"><a href="test.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></li>
              </ul>              
        </ul>            
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Css

```
.error {
color: white;
font-weight:bold;
background:#FF6666;
 list-style-type:none;
  border-left: 15px solid #E82C0C;
  margin-bottom:1px;
  padding: 5px;

}
.green{
background:#CCFFCC;
 list-style-type:none;
  border-left: 15px solid #7FFF7F;
  margin-bottom:1px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.yellow{
background:#FFFF66;
 list-style-type:none;
  border-left: 15px solid #FFDE59;
  margin-bottom:1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

div {
padding: 10px 10px;
margin-bottom:20px;
min-width: 768px;
max-width: 1024px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skiuljko/pzszuo3f/
thanks

Comment: Where’s the problem? You just specify a different `list-style-image` for each of your three classes, and done …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is hard to follow, but is this what you want? I only did it for .error, but it will give each level of .error elements a different picture.

Add `class="container"` to your first div (to give a reference position) and add this to your css:

```
.container > ul > .error {
    list-style-image: url(http://placehold.it/50x30/ff0000);
}
.container > ul > ul > .error {
    list-style-image: url(http://placehold.it/50x30/cc0000);
}
.container > ul > ul > ul > .error {
    list-style-image: url(http://placehold.it/50x30/aa0000);
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/lavorepo/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not completely clear but I guess you are looking for something like this:
You can use CSS specificity in order to target the right element.

```
.error {
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#FF6666;
      list-style-image: url(http://thekerrcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/bulletpoint.png);
    border-left: 15px solid #E82C0C;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    padding: 5px;
}
ul ul .error{
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#FF6666;
    list-style-image: url(http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/isleoftune/images/1/1b/Bullet_Point.png);
    border-left: 15px solid #E82C0C;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Or alternatively you can use the classes you already have (.yellow, etc.) to change the list images.

**DEMO** http://jsbin.com/jilolofi/1/edit